# how I record audio in custom chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, chrome-custom-tabs, recordrtc

I'm trying to record audio on website of mine 
the website is like sarahaha you share your link on the social media ex: Facebook and messenger and get feedback by voice message

https://www.atklem.com/users/MohamedDeux/08d68eb1-e5a4-9572-bd40-08777437c2b8

This is the kind of links that users share to their friends

I'm thinking that facebook is using [Custom Chrome Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) to open the link instead of the native chrome app

my problem: we can't record audio in this custom tab because of not getting the permission dialog to Allow recording audio ([get user Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia))

we currently using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) js library 
How can we solve this problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

currently on android the original app must give chrome custom tap permissions to access microphone like this

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
        request.grant(request.getResources());
    }
});
```

i believe facebook app doesn't do so and it does not work on ios too.

see this

> https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/issues/250#issuecomment-336240953